# JavaScript returning a promise even though it prints a string to the console

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

I'm trying to make a function that returns a string containing a jwt token, the function used in Amplify returns a promise and I can't get my head around promises but after some struggling, I've managed to get my function to get the string I need from the promise and print it to the console but when I then return this string from the function so I can call it from various places the resulting data is now a promise again. No idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
async function getToken() {
  let userData = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(result => result.signInUserSession).then(result => result.accessToken).then(result => result.jwtToken);
  console.log(userData); // this prints the token perfectly as text to the console
  return(userData); // I want this to return the token as a string not a promise
}

console.log(getToken(); // this prints a promise to the console again even though I've got it to a string in the function.
```

Comment: when functions are defined as async, they always return a promise

Comment: so at what point can I break out of the promise to return just my string?

Comment: Yeah async functions are just promises :). I know its confusing at first

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think I've sussed it now thanks to @tfarmer4 and @Arish Khan. In my head I wanted to get the token as a string variable so I could pass it into my API call functions but I realise now I will need to call it from within each function so below is my example solution.

```
function getToken() {
  return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(result => result.signInUserSession).then(result => result.accessToken).then(result => result.jwtToken);
}

function callAPI () {
  getToken().then(data => {
    let token = data;
    console.log(token);
    //more lines here such as calling my API using token as the variable of the jwt token
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: glad I could help. I struggled with this for a while when trying to understand promises as well. Just have to memorize the patterns associated with each approach because you'll see all the different syntax mixed in one development project a lot of times.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: [Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-mountain-mvvpf?file=/index.js) All you need is this edit I believe. Remember that async functions are just promises. You have to do any work on the result by either setting the result to a variable with an `let data = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(result => result).then(data => data.jwtToken)`, or just do all the necessary work in the `.then(data => {data.jwtToken //...your work here})`.

Comment: that is still giving me a promise, its so confusing.

Comment: @MattM see my sandbox

Answer (score -1):

If you have used await inside a function than it will only return a Promise no matter what so you can just use

```
getToken().then(console.log)

// or

getToken().then(token => console.log(token))

// both are same
```

since you can not use await outside an async function as a matter of react application just use state such as update the state of application using `setState()` in the `.then` of the promise returned. there is no such need of making the function async.

or if you really want the component to be async than just study `<Suspense>` in react to handle the components that have to fetch data from a network before being displayed

use it like this.

```
let result = null
getToken().then(token => {
    result = token

    // Now you can use the result variable
    console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: That writes it perfectly to the console but how do I get that string as a variable? I'm thinking something like getToken().then(result => { return result }); but that returned a promise again

Comment: I have updated answer